ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Revision '****' is not ready... Image 'us-central1.pkg.dev/****/****/${{github.sha}}:latest' not found
I am running this is my terminal but the latest tag is not resolving to the image-digest and gcloud says it cannot find the image even though it exists.
this is how I am building my image
      - name: build and deploy to GAR
        id: docker
        run: |-
          docker build -t us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/*****/*****/${{github.sha}}:latest .
          docker push us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/*****/*****/${{github.sha}}:latest

gcloud run deploy github-oidc-service \
          --image=us-central1.pkg.dev/****/****/21b54248299f5d32512b5b1584ab4780f2d800ed:latest \
          --region=us-central1 \
          --service-account=******@******.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Deploying container to Cloud Run service [github-oidc-service] in project [******] region [us-central1]
X Deploying...

Creating Revision...
. Routing traffic...
Deployment failed
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Revision 'github-oidc-service-00003-2hs' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. Image 'us-central1.pkg.dev///21b54248299f5d32512b5b1584ab4780f2d800ed:latest' not found

I am running the run deploy command in my github action and gcloud.run.deploy says it cannot find my image, even though the image exists, I tried with the image-digest and it works. So the issue is the lastest tag is not resolving to the image digest.
The image gets deployed to GAR and it has the latest tag. So the image has the github.sha has at the root level, inside of the image, it has a image-digest and the latest tag. I should be able to refer to the image and tag using image:latest, but I keep getting image not found.
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Revision 'github-oidc-service-00003-2hs' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. Image 'us-central1.pkg.dev/******/******/21b54248299f5d32512b5b1584ab4780f2d800ed:latest' not found 

